# PHP class returns echo but not bool

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to classes.

My Class:

```
if(!class_exists('my_connections')) {
    class my_connections {

        /* --------------- CHECKS IF CONNECTION EXISTS */
        public function is_connection($member_id, $connection_id) {

        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_connections` WHERE `member_id` = '".$member_id."' AND `connection_id` = '".$connection_id."'";
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

        //echo '<pre>'. $sql .'</pre>';

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            echo "YES THEY ARE FRIENDS";
            //$return = true;

        } else {

            echo "NO THEY ARE NOT FRIENDS"; 
            //$return = false;
        }

        //return $return;

        //echo $return;
        } // EO method - is_connection


    } // EO class

} //EO if !class_exists
```

Instantiate here:

```
$mc = new my_connections;

$test = $mc->is_connection('2154', '139');

echo $test;
```

It returns the echo statements just fine, but is not returning boolean,

for eg: instead of

```
echo $test;
```

I want to run a check against the method:

like so:

```
if ($test) {
  //do something
}
```

the echo statements inside the method will be replaced with return true / false

Comment: For reference, there's no such thing as "returning" an `echo` statement (short of returning a closure or function name that does the output).

Comment: You have echo "YES THEY ARE FRIENDS"; in the function. I should be $return = true; which is commented in the code

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes since it didnt work.

Comment: Also, `mysql_query` is deprecated.  Switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @cHao I have inherited a legacy application - I will slowly 'modernize' it.

Comment: @t.niese why is $test always false? I dont understand

Comment: @maximl337 sorry i read your question the wrong way, i'll deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
if(!class_exists('my_connections')) {
    class my_connections { 

        public function is_connection($member_id, $connection_id) {

        global $db;    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_connections` WHERE `member_id` = '".$member_id."' AND `connection_id` = '".$connection_id."'";
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

        return mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ;   
    }      
}
```

**And after check:**

```
if(is_connection($member_id, $connection_id)){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: This ternary serves no purpose: `return mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ? true : false;`. It's exactly the same as `return mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;`

Comment: @sergio That actually proves my point. `4 > 2 ? true : false;` is true. `4 > 2;` is also true. Finally, `((4 > 2 ? true : false) === (4 > 2))` is also true, which proves that the ternary is useless.

Comment: @MrLore. Huh, Now I undersood. Eh, thanks, problem was in incorrect translation of your comment:) I thought that ternary serves was wrong. But instead of ternar, I can just `return mysql_num_rows($result) > 0`. Thanks for advice!!

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as below

```
if(!class_exists('my_connections')) {
    class my_connections {

        /* --------------- CHECKS IF CONNECTION EXISTS */
        public function is_connection($member_id, $connection_id) {

        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_connections` WHERE `member_id` = '".$member_id."' AND `connection_id` = '".$connection_id."'";
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

        //echo '<pre>'. $sql .'</pre>';

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

           // echo "YES THEY ARE FRIENDS";
            return true;

        } else {

            //echo "NO THEY ARE NOT FRIENDS"; 
            return false;
        }

        //return $return;

        //echo $return;
        } // EO method - is_connection


    } // EO class

} //EO if !class_exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your class:

```
if(!class_exists('my_connections')) {
    class my_connections {

        /* --------------- CHECKS IF CONNECTION EXISTS */
        public function is_connection($member_id, $connection_id) {

            global $db;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_connections` WHERE `member_id` = '".$member_id."' AND `connection_id` = '".$connection_id."'";
            $result = @mysql_query($sql,$db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                echo "YES THEY ARE FRIENDS"; // message is echoed when you call this method
                return true; // your variable is set 
            } 
            else {
                echo "NO THEY ARE NOT FRIENDS"; 
                return false;
            }
        }
    } // EO class
} //EO if !class_exists
```

And your code:

```
 $mc = new my_connections;

 $test = $mc->is_connection('2154', '139'); // will automatically echo something from the class and set $test to true or false
```